# Request in javascript like Python requests

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, upload, puppeteer

I have python selenium code before and migrating to javascript puppeteer rigth now but face some problem on uploading my screenshot element for any page. There's my python code for upload image

```
file = {'fileToUpload': open('./up/' + emiten + '.png', 'rb')}
    resp = requests.post('/upload.php',
                           files=file)
    print(resp.text)
```

I use .php file for receive any image directly

```
<?php
$target_dir = "upload/";
$watermarkImagePath = 'wm.png';
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Kepentok kah? ";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Maaf gabisa usil.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){
      $watermarkImg = imagecreatefrompng($watermarkImagePath);
      $im = imagecreatefrompng($target_file);

      $marge_right = 17;
                 
      $sx = imagesx($watermarkImg);

      imagecopy($im, $watermarkImg, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($watermarkImg), imagesy($watermarkImg));
                 
      imagepng($im, $target_file);
      imagedestroy($im);
      
        echo "Upload file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " telah berhasil.";
    } else {
        echo "Maaf gabisa usil.";
    }
}
?>
```

Is there's any same method in javascript? Already using axios with formData dan nodefetch but nothing work
I hope there's simple code in javascript without change my .php file

Comment: Please share your axios and node-fetch code.

Comment: you can do it with fetch / formData but puppeteer can upload that file a lot easier